# Brand new water heater not working

Tags: water-heater

We just brought a new water heater and everything inside such as elements and the thermostats are all perfectly working.

The wiring is all good and the connections are all good but the water heater still doesn’t make hot water.

Any ideas on how to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Does it have sufficient water pressure?

Comment: How do you know everything is "perfectly working" if it doesn't make hot water?

Comment: Was it hooked up backwards? I would agree with @tnknepp.

Comment: @EdBeal How can it be hooked up backward?  Heating elements shouldn't care if hot and neutral are swapped, should it?

Comment: Perhaps  Ed was asking if the water  connections are "backwards"  ?

Comment: Perhaps this question will provide some helpful info. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/did-the-plumber-hook-up-my-water-heater-backwards

Comment: Yeah, check to make sure you've hooked the water supply to the cold water port and the hot water line to the outlet port -- if you get the water lines backwards, hot water will basically "short circuit" around the water heater, and you'll get lukewarm water out at best

Comment: Yes I was talking about the water connections there is a supply line and a output of these are backwards you guessed it the water heater won’t work correctly.

Comment: One of the things you cited in your question (elements, thermostats, wiring, connections) are **NOT** "all good". How about some pics?

Comment: be sure you have the hot and cold connections correct. The cold water supply MUST be connected to the cold side. tank type water heaters have a "dip tube" that directs the cold water to the botttom of the heater. If your plumbing connections are reversed, the best you would get is luke warm water.